# Too Many Connections Error: Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, servlets, connection-pooling

I am using Hibernate in my web application which is developed with pure Servlet and JSP. I am facing to a big trouble "sometimes" when I execute the code. What happens is I am getting `Too many Connections` error from Hibernate.

I went through lot of Stackoverflow questions seeking for an answer and I found different solutions. Some suggested to use a third party pooling system, some suggested to be thread safe, some suggested to be using one `SessionFactory` etc, therefor I am not sure which one is applicable to mine.

Below is a portion of my database layer.

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;
import model.main.Familyvisa;
import model.main.Familyvisa;
import model.main.Familyvisa;
import model.main.Pensionhistory;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class FamilyVisaImpl implements FamilyVisaInterface
{
    private Session currentSession; 
    private Transaction currentTransaction;

        public Session openCurrentSession() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void closeCurrentSession() {
        currentSession.close();
    }

    public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.commit();
        currentSession.close();
    }

    private static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
            return sessionFactory;
    }

       public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return currentSession;
    }

    public void setCurrentSession(Session currentSession) {
        this.currentSession = currentSession;
    }

    public Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return currentTransaction;
    }

    public void setCurrentTransaction(Transaction currentTransaction) {
        this.currentTransaction = currentTransaction;
    }

         @Override
    public void save(Familyvisa entity) {
        getCurrentSession().save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Familyvisa entity) {
        getCurrentSession().update(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Familyvisa findById(int id) {
        Familyvisa book = (Familyvisa) getCurrentSession().get(Familyvisa.class, id);
        return book; 
    }

     @Override
    public void delete(Familyvisa entity) {
        getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
    }   

    @Override
        public List<Familyvisa> findAll() {
        List<Familyvisa> remDur = (List<Familyvisa>) getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Familyvisa").list();
        return remDur;
    }




     public Familyvisa findByForiegnKey_Family(int idFamily) 
    {
        String hql = "FROM  Familyvisa WHERE idFamily = :famId";
        //String hql = "FROM  Visa WHERE idFamily = :famId";
        Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
        q.setParameter("famId", idFamily);

        Familyvisa v = new Familyvisa();

        if(!q.list().isEmpty())
        {
            v = (Familyvisa)q.list().get(0);
        }

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(Familyvisa p) 
    {
        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(p);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Object[]> findReminderActiveVisaWithFamilyAndEmployee() 
    {
        String sql = "";

        SQLQuery createSQLQuery = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
        return createSQLQuery.list();
    }

    @Override
    public void batchUpdate(List<Familyvisa> list)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            getCurrentSession().update(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my service layer, related to the above code.

```
package service;

import dao.FamilyVisaImpl;
import java.util.List;
import model.main.Familyvisa;


/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class FamilyVisaService
{
     private FamilyVisaImpl familyVisaImpl;

    public FamilyVisaService()
    {
        familyVisaImpl = new FamilyVisaImpl();
    }

    public Familyvisa findByForiegnKey_Family(int idFamily)
    {
        familyVisaImpl.openCurrentSession();
        Familyvisa findByForiegnKey_Family = familyVisaImpl.findByForiegnKey_Family(idFamily);
        familyVisaImpl.closeCurrentSession();
        return findByForiegnKey_Family;
    }

    public List<Object[]> findReminderActiveVisaWithFamilyAndEmployee()
    {
        familyVisaImpl.openCurrentSession();
         List<Object[]> visa = familyVisaImpl.findReminderActiveVisaWithFamilyAndEmployee();
        familyVisaImpl.closeCurrentSession();
        return visa;
    }

    public void batchUpdate(List<Familyvisa> list)
    {
        familyVisaImpl.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        familyVisaImpl.batchUpdate(list);
        familyVisaImpl.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }
}
```

Below is a code from Servlet, which explains how I execute the code.

```
private void updateDatabase(List<VisaWithFamilyAndEmployeeBean> reminderSentList)
    {
        FamilyVisaService service = new FamilyVisaService();
        List<Familyvisa> visa = new ArrayList<Familyvisa>();

        for(int i=0;i<reminderSentList.size();i++)
        {
            Familyvisa familyVisa = service.findByForiegnKey_Family(reminderSentList.get(i).getIdFamily());
            familyVisa.setNumberOfReminders(familyVisa.getNumberOfReminders()+1);
            familyVisa.setLastReminderSent(Common.getCurrentDateSQL());
            visa.add(familyVisa);
        }

        service.batchUpdate(visa);
    }
```

I have lot of classes in three layers (servlet, DAO, Service) and all follow the exact same structure, serving different purposes, but methods looks almost same (like update, insert etc).

Please pay some decent attention to the code, to the key words, usage of access specifiers etc. In some other classes, in service layer, I define it's IMPL as `static` as well eg: `private static EmployeeImpl employeeimpl;`

Can you find what is happening wrong here? Since it occures only "sometimes" and in any of the code (not only in here, but the other classes also same, only difference is they call to different tables) so I can figure it out.

**UPDATE**

Considering the comments and answers, I changed the code to below. Please let me know whether it is in quality level.

```
FamilyVisaService service = new FamilyVisaService();
Session session = service.openCurrentSession(); //This method will call openCurrentSession() in Impl class


try {

  for(int i=0;i<reminderSentList.size();i++)
    {
        /* findByForiegnKey_Family() has Session argument now! */
        Familyvisa familyVisa = service.findByForiegnKey_Family(session, reminderSentList.get(i).getIdFamily());
        familyVisa.setNumberOfReminders(familyVisa.getNumberOfReminders()+1);
        familyVisa.setLastReminderSent(Common.getCurrentDateSQL());
        visa.add(familyVisa);
    } 
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("ERROR:"+ex);
  } finally {
      session.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<reminderSentList.size();i++)
   {
      Familyvisa familyVisa = service.findByForiegnKey_Family(reminderSentList.get(i).getIdFamily());
      familyVisa.setNumberOfReminders(familyVisa.getNumberOfReminders()+1);
      familyVisa.setLastReminderSent(Common.getCurrentDateSQL());
      visa.add(familyVisa);
   }
```

opens and closes the session inside the loop multiple times during it's execution using `service.findByForeignKey_Family()` function.

Session openning and closing could take some time but the loop is fast enough. That's why could multiple sessions to be open: it's just need the time to be closed. And in your code it's actual. That's why "Too Many Connections" error occurs.

In other words, pass the `session` to the `service.findByForiegnKey_Family()` as parameter instead of openning and closing this inside function.

Like this:

```
Session session = ...
try {

  for(int i=0;i<reminderSentList.size();i++)
    {
        /* findByForiegnKey_Family() has Session argument now! */
        Familyvisa familyVisa = service.findByForiegnKey_Family(session, reminderSentList.get(i).getIdFamily());
        familyVisa.setNumberOfReminders(familyVisa.getNumberOfReminders()+1);
        familyVisa.setLastReminderSent(Common.getCurrentDateSQL());
        visa.add(familyVisa);
    } 
  } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("ERROR:"+ex);
  } finally {
      session.close();
  }
```

---

The above example is Thread-safe. Because you open, operate and close the session inside single function.

---

Hibernate requires transaction block even for read operations. So you have to fix your code like this:

```
Session session = ...
try {
session.beginTransaction();
...
Your Loop
...
session.getTransaction.commit();
...
```

Comment: Interesting, but seems like I have to make lot of changes?

Comment: @JustCause, actually you need just move opening and closing the session outside the `.findByForiegnKey_Family()` function and loop as well. + refuse from non-transactional operations. That's all

Comment: ah, So that your entire code comes inside of a function. OK, I thought the `session` is a global variable, because you have not declared a function.

Comment: I added an update, another small code with some changes, which I have changed according to the answers. Please take a look and let me know if any issues or whether it is OK.

Comment: You forgot transaction block. Would be better to add it to prevent unexpected results. The rest is ok, should work fine.

Comment: OK. Then all I have to do is calling to `openCurrentSessionwithTransaction()` instead of `openCurrentSession()`

Comment: Thank you for the continuous support and help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No, Transactions are exception throwable, that's why you have to put `.beginTransaction()` and `.getTransaction().commit()` inside try-catch block like in example at the end of an answer.

Comment: OK, Then I will declare `openCurrentSessionwithTransaction()` as `openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() throws Exception{body}`. How's that?

Comment: Then your caller function will throw this exception too. If you ready to handle this at the upper level, you can do this.

Comment: Yes of course. It is easy for us now, that is because 99% of the application is ready and this can avoid master "re coding"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong in so many ways:

1. The code is not Thread-safe, as you already admitted:

   ```
   private Session currentSession; 
   private Transaction currentTransaction;

   public Session openCurrentSession() {
       currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
       return currentSession;
   }

   public Session openCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
       currentSession = getSessionFactory().openSession();
       currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
       return currentSession;
   }

   public void closeCurrentSession() {
       currentSession.close();
   }

   public void closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction() {
       currentTransaction.commit();
       currentSession.close();
   }
   ```

   The Service layer singletons should never store state, because they are accessed by concurrent requests. What if you have a current running Session and a second request opens a new session as well? The first thread will never get the chance to close his session, but it will attempt to close the last opened session (e.g. currentSession).
2. The `Session` is not even thread-safe so you will bump into all sorts of weird concurrent modification or change visibility errors.
3. You should follow the Hibernate session management best practices and choose for a [session-per-request](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch02.html#session-per-request) solution backed by a ThreadLocal Session storage.
4. Adding [Spring Transaction Management](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/) is a simple and effective way of handling the connection/session/transaction management.

Comment: 1. It is not Thread safe because of the `class level` variables? But it is not in `Servlet` but in another class?
2. Didn't get the point.
3. Seems like "Close sessions inside `Finally block` ?
4. I guess we are too late.

Finally, what about the creation of `SessionFactory` ? As it seems, it is opening new instances everytime in the loop of `updateDatabase`

Comment: 1. Multiple requests can call `openCurrentSession` and therefore set the `session`, and each session should be bound to the calling Thread. In your case the `session` holds the last opened session, and that's not even thread-safe anyway. 3. Even if you call close on finally block, are you sure you close the `session` that you opened in the first place?

Comment: `1. Multiple requests can call openCurrentSession and therefore set the session, and each session should be bound to the calling Thread` - How can I do this?.. And pls check the `SessionFactory` as well, I am defining it inside a method..

Comment: `FamilyVisaService` is singleton and it has one `FamilyVisaImpl` instance. Multiple requests call the the `FamilyVisaService` methods, therefore calling `openCurrentSession()` concurrently. So the `session` variable is overwritten with each new `openCurrentSession()` call. Makes sense?

Comment: `FamilyVisaService ` is not singleton. I tried to make it one, but then I stopped. It is not singleton.

Comment: But where's the finally block, where you close the session? If you get an exception, the associated connection might never be closed, leading to "too many opened connections".

Comment: Inside the `Service`. For an example, pls have a look at `batchUpdate()` method. There is no finally block anyway. (No try catch too, I got this part of code from a tutorial as I was a newbie to hibernate. You might have got confused with the variable names, `familyVisa`. Wait, I will fix it.

Comment: Now please take a look.

Comment: Still no finally block. Check @wilddev example to see how you should use it to properly close all sessions.

Comment: I did. Now I have an idea, I will explain step by step.

Comment: I added an update, another small code with some changes, which I have changed according to the answers. Please take a look and let me know if any issues or whether it is OK

Comment: Thank you for the valuable advises. I really appreciate them. I already gave a +1.

Comment: It looks better, but I'd make the session/transaction local variables as opposed to being class attributes. This way you can make the service classes singletons too.

Comment: OK, I will move them to `openCurrentSessionWithTransaction()` and will pass it the `session` to all the methods including `save`